# Vue.js - Filtering inside v-for, how to handle if Array is actually null

Tags: vue.js

Hopefully this replica isn't too alien to the Vue.js world.

I have a list of profiles. Inside these profile instances there is an array that represents their socialMedia accounts. However, due to legacy database reasons, let's say that for some of the artists the socialMedia account comes through into the Vue.js application as `null`.

So, imagine I have something like:

```
<a
   v-if="artwork.artist.socialMedia"
   v-for="(social, index) in artwork.artist.socialMedia.filter(social => social.url.length > 0)"
   v-bind:key="index"
   v-bind:href="parseSocialMediaURL(social.url, social.platform)"
>

</a>
```

However, the preceding v-if statement, doesn't seem to be skipping past those values for `artwork.artist.socialMedia` when this is `null`. For most, this value is just a plain old `Array`, so how do I go about handling both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `v-if` should work, but if your condition is more complex than a simple `if` you can consider using a computed method for this. It could also handle the `filter` in it. You can also use `isArray` for a better check.

```
computed: {
  artistSocialMedia () {
    if( !Array.isArray(this.artwork.artist.socialMedia) ) {
     return []
    }

    return this.artwork.artist.socialMedia.filter(social => social.url.length > 0)
  }
}
```

and then use the computed method

```
<a
   v-for="(social, index) in artistSocialMedia"
   v-bind:key="index"
   v-bind:href="parseSocialMediaURL(social.url, social.platform)"
>

</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of the vue documentation, you should not be using them together https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for.

To render conditionally without adding addition elements wrap it in a template

```
<template v-if="artwork.artist.socialMedia">
    <a
        v-for="(social, index) in artwork.artist.socialMedia.filter(social => social.url.length > 0)"
        v-bind:key="index"
        v-bind:href="parseSocialMediaURL(social.url, social.platform)"
    >
    </a>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer but I think you skipped over the use case where `artwork.artist.socialMedia` is `null` (you can't filter a `null` value, only an `Array`)...please re-read the question.

Comment: the v-if at the top should handle this case.